# Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T', where T : Enum

Tags: generics, enums, type-constraints, enum-flags, c#-7.3

I have this enum with `Flags` attribute

```
[Flags]
public enum Animal
{
    Null = 0,
    Cat = 1,
    Dog = 2,
    CatAndDog = Cat | Dog
}
```

And use C# 7.3 which allows type constraints like:

```
where T : Enum
```

I create some extension method:

```
public static bool IsMoreOrEqualThan<T>(this T a, T b) where T : Enum
{
    return (a & b) == b;
}
```

It returns true if

1) Enum elements are comparable. For example: `Animal.Cat` and `Animal.Dog` are not comparable.

**AND**

2) Element a is more or equal than element b

Examples:

```
Animal.Cat.IsMoreOrEqualThan(Animal.Null)//true
Animal.Cat.IsMoreOrEqualThan(Animal.Cat)//true
Animal.Cat.IsMoreOrEqualThan(Animal.Dog)//false
Animal.Cat.IsMoreOrEqualThan(Animal.CatAndDog)//false
```

============================

**But i have compillation error:** `Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'`

It seems, like .Net developers forgot to allow bitwise operations beetween generic types which has type constraint `where T : Enum`

Maybe anyone knows the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same result with [HasFlag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag).

Answer (score 0):

I change my method this way

```
public static bool IsMoreOrEqualThan<T>(this T a, T b) where T : Enum
{
    return (Convert.ToInt32(a) & Convert.ToInt32(b)) == Convert.ToInt32(b);
}
```

and now It works